# Get all checkedout items of login user in sitecollection in sharepoint 2010 using jquery

Tags: web-part

My scenario is to get show the checked-out items of logged in user at site collection level. a web part to pull all the items checked-out by user .

Comment: I tried to customize the content query web part and was able to pull the checked out items but unable to get the location or path of the file. The files are opening directly . For example "test.docx" when i click on this it is asking me to save . I want something which takes me to the location of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way other than a webservice to achieve this if you want it through javascript.

OOTB way is of course to use the Content by Query web part, which you state you have already tried. Though it does not show the location, you can still modify the ItemStyle.xsl to show the URL at least.

If you want a more programmatic approach, you should look into [`SPSiteDataQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx).
Create either an application page (aka System Page) or a custom web part to display the results.

Here's an example on how to use the `SPSiteDataQuery`:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPSiteDataQuery siteDataQuery = new SPSiteDataQuery
        {
            Lists = "<Lists BaseType='1' />", 
            Query = String.Format(String.Concat("<Where>", 
                                                    "<Eq>",
                                                        "<FieldRef Name='CheckOutUser' LookupId='TRUE' />", 
                                                        "<Value Type='int'>{0}</Value>", 
                                                    "</Eq>",
                                                "</Where>"), web.CurrentUser.ID),
            Webs = "<Webs Scope='SiteCollection' />", 
            ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='SomeOtherProperty' />"          
        }
    }
}
```